# Offline installation of Rails greater than 2.3.4 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, installation, offline

I have an intranet only server unable to connect the web even through a proxy, so I always used to update Ruby gems via downloaded gems and the command (e.g for rails):

> gem install 'rails-x.y.z.gem'

Now I've got to upgrade rails to, at least, 2.3.11, but can't find that release's gem on RubyForge.
Releases on RF seem to end at 2.3.4... 
I guess I'm missing some very basic requirement.

Can someone help me?

Thanks,

Andrea Colleoni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it on rubygems - http://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions